# Как реализовать в Spring Security роли унаследованные от класса User?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

**Всем привет! Пишу проект, необходима помощь, так как не нашёл на просторах ответа...**

Есть класс `User`. У него есть наследники `Customer` и `Seller`.

Дело в том, что не могу понять, как настроить модели и `SecurityConfig` так, чтобы Spring при авторизации `Customer`'a или `Seller`'a, определял, что логинится `Customer` или `Seller`.

User.class

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String login;

    private String password;

    @Email
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Role.class

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Customer.class

```
import com.jm.spare_parts_shop.model.auto.Car;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table
public class Customer extends User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "customers_cars",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"))
    private Set<Car> carSet;

}
```

Seller.class

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table
public class Seller extends User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "sellers_suppliers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "seller_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id"))
    private Set<Supplier> sellerSet;

}
```

SecurityConfig.class

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration/**").not().fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers("/customer/**").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                .antMatchers("/seller/**").hasRole("SELLER")
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Ну и вдруг нужен

LoginSuccessHandler.class

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

public class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {


        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());

        
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_CUSTOMER")) {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/customer");
         } else if (roles.contains("ROLE_SELLER")) {
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/seller");
        } else {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/registration");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем так?..зачем наследовать?.. просто двух ролей недоcтаточно?

Comment: Такое решение было заложено изначально. Есть аннотация @Inheritance. С помощью неё я справился с задачей.

Comment: По-моему это "изначально плохое решение". Из-за которого вы сейчас и испытываете трудности